# Magento Revenue Report

Tags: refund

Just wanted to check. Regarding the revenue report under Reports > Sales > Orders, when I cancel the order, the amount refunded will show on the refunded column right? The "invoiced'' amount is the amount less the refunded amount, correct?

2nd question is if I do a partial refund via Paypal, does Magento automatically detect this and adjusts the invoiced amount on the reports accordingly? Or do I need to do anything? If I need to manually adjust the figure, how can I go about doing it?

Appreciate your help guys!

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0):

1. correct
2. magento will display original invoiced amount and partial refund amount.

   - if you do partial refund, magento mark all products as refunded.